# Developing Facebook App (connect) on localhost

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm developing a facebook app using the javascript sdk on localhost.  I've added the domain to the canvas url and setup my hosts file to point it to 127.0.0.7.  When I go to the domain, it resolves as expected.

I've setup this domain as the canvas URL within facebook.

I have the following code and the problem is the page just continues to refresh over and over again.

```
FB.init({ 
    appId:'XXXXXXXXXXX', cookie:true, 
    status:true, xfbml:true 
});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
    window.location.reload();
});

$('.logout_fb').click(function(){
    FB.logout(function(){
        window.location.reload();                  
    });
});
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook needs to be able to reach your web server.  Does it work when you host it on an external server?